# EL ExpressionFactory, scopes, JSTL forEach tag, iterated variable: where is?

Tags: jsp, scope, jstl, el

I am working with ExpressionFactory inside my program, and I wan to make ValueExpressions and variables be accessible from JSP with EL expressions.

I can't understand something: looks like my variables I put way override normal variables, for example, those set by forEach tag when iterating. I am thinking that my code puts user in a pageScope, and obvoiusly so does forEach tag, but I am wrong.

How should I work with factory and value expressions, so that I can access variables unless they are overridden, not vice versa like in the following example?:

```
<%@page import="javax.el.ValueExpression"%>
<%@page import="javax.el.ELContext"%>
<%@page import="javax.el.ExpressionFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Check Scopes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <%
      ExpressionFactory ef = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().
              getJspApplicationContext(application).getExpressionFactory();
      ELContext ec = pageContext.getELContext();
      ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(ec, "humangus", String.class);
      pageContext.getELContext().getVariableMapper().setVariable("user", ve);
      String[]users = new String[]{"mike", "bob", "kate"};
      pageContext.setAttribute("users", users);
      %>

    <h3>List of Users:</h3>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="status">
      ${status.count}: 
without specifying scope: ${user}, 
from page scope: ${pageScope.user}<br/>
    </c:forEach>


  </body>
</html>
```

This produces the following:

**List of Users:**

1: without specifying scope: humangus, from page scope: mike

2: without specifying scope: humangus, from page scope: bob

3: without specifying scope: humangus, from page scope: kate

Comment: My jaw just felt on the ground... Can you please elaborate the functional requirement in more detail? It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve/solve this way.

Comment: @BalusC! thank you!! elaborations follow...

Comment: @BalusC the scriptlet part wouldn't be scriptlet, this is just for example to show. It would be a code in some other class/method that would be called before the main jsp output. After it finishes working, there must be some variables put in some scope, request or page, so that I could access them through simple expressions like ${user}. But, they should be able to be set to any other value. In my example, the forEach tag, it's "var" attribute, should override the value I previously put in ${user}. (But it seems I unintentionally put my value to some scope with higher priority)

Comment: and forgot to say, it should work with expressions like I tried, because there is actually a custom wrapper of a VariableMapper there. It first resolves a variable, and then puts the result as shown in the example...

Comment: Then just set it in the scope the usual way? E.g. `request.setAttribue("user", "humangus");`? Or am I totally missing the point? Why would you like to use the `VariableMapper`?

Comment: this is sorta long story, put short (and maybe even more vague) - I am making a web form parameters acquirer; the query parameter names and values could contain el expressions. like this: create=user&user.name=robert&user.login=bob ... of any complexity, so i am trying to take advantage of EL. "create" commands should create objects and put them so that other commands would be valid EL expressions (i make sure "creates" processed first). It already works! Now I am trying to make created objects be available afterwards and accessed through ELs :) dont laugh plz

Comment: when my form processor meets "user.name", my `VariableMapper` wrapper is called, checks whether any "create" command that creates "user" exists, and if it exists, performs object creation and puts expression ${user} to the `ELContext` I passed to it (`pageContext`). I need to note that I am trying to make it detachable from web and jsp contexts, my method takes `ELContext` and `ExpressionFactory` as parameters, so it could potentially work in standalone programs.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I have the impression that variables set by `VariableMapper` have simply precedence in EL resolving over `PageContext#findAttribute()`. As far now I'm not sure how to go about this, never done it like that before.

Comment: @BalusC thanks. I am always doing something that not so many people done before. That's my bad karma. I'll ask in Tomcat mailing list, maybe it's a bug, or a behaviour that couldn't be avoided without much work that no-one would do for me only.

Comment: After some thought, I *think* I would rather have used a `Filter` on `*.jsp` which does the request parameter deciphering job and just puts the object map as a request attribute. Did you consider this?

Comment: Yes, the big part of job is done in a filter; though I am trying to make a module that would not depend on servlet api, __and__ let the .jsp author control what would be put in an object. So, the set of commands is prepared in a filter, put into a request attribute, then the jsp starts; we can add those fields that shouldn't come from a form (or a user could send, for example, future date or something) to that set, and call a procedure to create all objects and fill their fields... The idea of making this procedure reusable outside of web context (use only EL) makes my life bit harder.

Comment: @BalusC, you help me (and many others) so much! I think I let the variables be that prioritized and mention this in my docs, 'don't call foreach vars as your form vars'; I may also put them in some special variable, like ${formData.user}, I see how to do it

Comment: I'd go for the latter approach. Most developers ignores documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your code.

```
  <%
     pageContext.setAttribute("user", "humangus");
     String[]users = new String[]{"mike", "bob", "kate"};
     pageContext.setAttribute("users", users);
  %>
Before forEach loop user is ${user}!<br/>
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="status">
  ${status.count} user is ${user}<br/>
</c:forEach>
After forEach loop user is ${user}!
```

Output: 
Before forEach loop user is humangus!
1 user is mike
2 user is bob
3 user is kate
After forEach loop user is !

??? Curiously, no value is found after the forEach loop.

Comment: this might be logical at least: the loop ended, the value deleted. the engine doesn't organize a stack to recall the value before the loop, and the loops may be nested